# Multiple values from redis with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-redis

I've been trying to figure out how to achieve something like this with nodejs and redis:

```js
    var var1 = redisClient.get("foo");
    var var2 = redisClient.get("bar");
    if (var1 && var2) {
        do_something();
    } else {
        do_something_else();
    }
```

I know that redis calls are asynchronous but repeating something like:

```js
var var1, var2;
redisClient.get("foo", function(err, data) {
  var1 = data;
  redisClient.get("bar", function(err, data) {
    var2 = data;
    
    if (var1 && var2) {
      do_something(); 
    } else {
      do_something_else();
    }
  }
});
```

Doesn't feel right to do every time I want to access those two variables.

Comment: Using mget may solve your problem

redisClient.mget(["foo", "bar"], function (err, res) {
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to control your flow:

```
    async.parallel([
         function(done) {
             redisClient.get("foo",done);
         },
         function(done) {
             redisClient.get("bar",done);
         }
       ],
       function(err, result) {
             //result[0] here is foo
            //result[1] here is bar
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just thought whole thing in the wrong way.